# Splash screen keep refreshing itself in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I want to display a splash screen that when I first run my program, the splash screen will be shown and then redirect the user to the main page. I was following a tutorial for this code block and it redirected the user to http://www.google.com, so not a problem. But i want to redirect the user to my asp.net page which is the GetGoogleDriveFiles view. I tried to do it like this.

It will first show the splash screen when I run it. And then after a few seconds, it will redirect to the main page of the program. But then within a second, it refreshes itself and loop the splash screen and the whole process again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    (function () {

        var preload = document.getElementById("preload");
        var loading = 0;
        var id = setInterval(frame, 64);

        function frame() {
            if (loading == 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
                window.location.href = "/Home/GetGoogleDriveFiles";
            }
            else {
                loading = loading + 1;
                if (loading == 90) {
                    preload.style.animation = "fadeout 1s ease";
                }
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

How can I ensure that once the program is run, it will redirect user to the main page of my program instead of constantly refreshing itself again?

**ADDED CSS AND UPDATED WITH NEW JS**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.preload {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 150px auto 50px auto;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-shadow: -1px 2px 2px #000;
    text-align: center;
    color: azure;
}

.loader-frame {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.loader1, .loader2 {
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.loader1 {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-top: 5px solid azure;
    border-bottom: 5px solid azure;
    animation: clockwisespin 2s linear 3;
}

.loader2 {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border-left: 5px solid darkturquoise;
    border-right: 5px solid darkturquoise;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    animation: anticlockwisespin 2s linear 3;
}

@@keyframes clockwisespin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

@@keyframes anticlockwisespin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@@keyframes fadeout {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

 <div class="preload" id="preload">
    <div class="logo">
         Loa<span style="color: darkturquoise;">ding</span>
    </div>
    <div class="loader-frame">
        <div class="loader1" id="loader1"></div>
        <div class="loader2" id="loader2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeOutInMilliSeconds = 10000;
    setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "/Home/GetGoogleDriveFiles";
    }, timeOutInMilliSeconds);
</script>
```

I have updated with the css and the js code but still the splash screen shows but keeps looping and does not display the GetGoogleDriveFiles page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the script could be much simpler. Like the script below which just goes to the new url after 5 seconds. You can do what you want in that period, like showing a splash screen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var timeOutInMilliSeconds = 5000;

    setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "/Home/GetGoogleDriveFiles";
    }, timeOutInMilliSeconds);

    //do stuff here before redirect, like showing splash screen

</script>
```

Comment: I have added the css and updated the js code like yours but the splash screen still keeps looping and does not display my view of GetGoogleDriveFiles.